# Which WinAPI function checks permissions of a specific file/folder?

Tags: winapi, permissions, file-permissions

I'm looking for a WinAPI function that will tell me what the user which is using the program can and can not do with specific file or folder.

Thanks,

Comment: If only it were that simple! The MSDN topics on the subject start  here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375769(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: You are probably looking for the [`GetFileSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.